# How can I find a font that contains a given character?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a font that I use for my app which only uses english characters. I use `CoreText` to display the text, and I notice that whenever someone enters a character that isn't included in the font (like an Arabic character), then the program hangs at this line:

```
CTFramesetterCreateFrame(textFramesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), textMutablePath, NULL);
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. is it possible to know if a certain character is included in a font?
2. is it possible for the system to find a font that contains the unknown character?

#### Related: [Check if certain character is supported by UIFont](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622219/check-if-certain-character-is-supported-by-uifont)

Comment: . The other post has your answer on a character basis, but you probably need to query a font manager for supported languages and monitor a change in input methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) Is it possible to know if a certain character is included in a font?

```
BOOL FontContainsCharacter(UIFont *font, unichar character) {
    NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [font.fontDescriptor objectForKey:UIFontDescriptorCharacterSetAttribute];
    return [characterSet characterIsMember:character];
}
```

2) Is it possible for the system to find a font that contains the unknown character?

```
NSArray *FontDescriptorsForFontsContainingCharactersInString(NSString *string) {
    NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:string];
    NSDictionary *fontAttributes = @{UIFontDescriptorCharacterSetAttribute:characterSet};
    UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes:fontAttributes];
    return [fontDescriptor matchingFontDescriptorsWithMandatoryKeys:nil];
}
```

For example:

```
NSLog(@"%d", FontContainsCharacter([UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12], 0x0041)); // "A"
NSLog(@"%d", FontContainsCharacter([UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12], 0x4F60)); // "你"

for (UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor in FontDescriptorsForFontsContainingCharactersInString(@"你好")) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontDescriptor size:12].fontName);
}
```

Output:

```
1
0
STHeitiSC-Light
STHeitiSC-Medium
STHeitiTC-Light
STHeitiTC-Medium
HiraKakuProN-W3
HiraKakuProN-W6
HiraMinProN-W3
HiraMinProN-W6
```

Comment: THat's a great answer, thanks. Just curious but do you happen to know anyone font that covers the most languages? For instance, is it safe to use the Apple system font for an unknown character?

Comment: Not sure about the font covering the most languages. You can't assume the system font has glyphs for all characters. Also, be aware that the system font may change with the locale.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my first question and is based on a response from Rob Mayoff in this other question: [CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393076/ctfontgetglyphsforcharacters-always-returns-false)

```
- (BOOL) textExistsInFont:(NSString *)text
{
    CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)self.fontName, self.fontSize, NULL);
    NSUInteger count = text.length;
    unichar characters[count];
    [text getCharacters:characters range:NSMakeRange(0, count)];
    CGGlyph glyphs[count];

    if (CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(fontRef, characters, glyphs, count) == false)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

My second question I'm still working on but am getting the impression that the Apple system font (Helvetica Neue) covers many languages. Want to verify though. So if the character isn't in the font you're using, then switching to the system font might be a viable alternative.